# Solving a system of equalities using a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, gradient-descent

Assume $P$ is a set of pairs $(x, y)$,
where both $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Assume $P'$ is a subset of $P$.

I want to train a neural network
$N: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$
such that, for any pair $(x, y)$ in $P'$,
I get $N(x) = N(y)$.
Let's call this constraint $C_1$.
I also want to enforce some other constraints
on $P \setminus P'$,
which are not necessarily satisfied when
$C_1$ is also satisfied for $(x, y)$ in $P \setminus P'$.
For example, when $m = 1$,
I define $C_2$ as $N(x) - N(y) \geq 1$
for all $(x, y)$ in $P \setminus P'$.

What I have observed is that, after training,
almost always one of the following cases happens:

1. $N$ becomes a trivial answer for $C_1$;
   e.g., $N(x) = 0$ for any $x$.
2. $N$ satisfies all of the constraints, except for $C_1$.

Why is this almost always the case?
Is there a way to avoid this,
e.g. by adding some term to my loss function?

Edit: added an example for another constraint.

Comment: What happens if you have $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ in your $P^{\prime}$ for $x_1 = (1,2,3)$, $x_2=(1, 2, 3)$, $y_1 = (4, 5, 6)$, and $y_2 = (4, 5, 7)?$ How do you ensure that $N(x_1)=N(y_1)$ *and* $N(x_2) = N(y_2)?$

Comment: @Dave for this particular example, $N(x_1) = N(x_2) = N(y_1) = N(y_2)$ is a valid answer for $C_1$. Also, showing $N(x_1) = N(y_1)$ _and_ $N(x_2) = N(y_2)$ is not harder than showing $N(x) = N(y)$ for _every_ $(x, y)$ in $P'$. Did I miss something from your question?

Comment: You have to have some way to send unequal points to the same output. Isn't a constant output the way to ensure that?

Comment: @Dave Indeed. Let us also assume I have another pair $(x_0, y_0)$ in $P \setminus P'$, and the _other constraint_ is $C_2$, defined as $N(x_0) - N(y_0) \geq 1$. Yet, my network either learns to output zero for everything (hence negating $C_2$), or to just satisfy $C_2$ and ignore $C_1$ for almost all points in $P'$. My question really is: how can I get the network to satisfy both $C_1$ and $C_2$, without almost completely ignoring either of them?